# checkbox rename in excel macro

Tags: vb.net, excel, macros

I would like to create an excel macro, in which I create some chechboxes. When I record the macro, I choose the properties of the chechbox in edit mode, then on the left side i give new position values, size values, name and caption to the chechbox. But the macro itself don't remember, just the size and position values.

It will be in the visual basic code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=128.25, Top:=84.75, Width:=108, Height:= _
        21).Select
```

When I try to write in the code itself, that `Caption:="xyz"`, that will be error.
How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this via your VBA macro. Then the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097761/excel-vba-renaming-checkboxes) (not answers) can provide the syntax needed.

Otherwise, the following should work, it's not the cleanest but does the job (hat tip to Google for finding [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/681340-visual-basic-applications-change-caption-activex-checkboxes-using-loop.html)):

```
Sub test()
Dim obj As OLEObject
Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
obj.Name = "checkboxx"
obj.Object.Caption = "CAPTION"
End Sub
```

Note that you will not be able to run this using the Step Into functionality of VBA (F8).

Comment: Thanks, i tried to interpret that syntax, but something is still wrong. Can you help with this?                                                                                                                                                               Dim obj As OLEObject
     ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False).Select
    With Worksheets("Munka1")
    For Each obj In .OLEObjects
    If TypeName(obj.Object) = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then

            obj.Name = "chechboxx"
            obj.Caption = "CAPTION"
      
    End If
    Next obj
    End With

Comment: Are you sure that you need a _ActiveX Control_, rather than a _Form Control_?

Comment: Form controls are easier to manipulate in my opinion. Anyhow, I edited the answer and now it should work for you.

Comment: As i tried, the checkbox.Caption = "asdf" doesnt work with form control too... i dont understand

Comment: OK, it works with form control. Really the application won't be so difficult, so i hope it will be enaugh. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6MXm.png)

Comment: Thanks, it works for the name, but not for the caption. It writes into the code this: Selection.Name = "xyz", but i would like to rewrite the caption too.